# How to I reference an image I've added to a storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Working in Xcode 5 for ios 6 up. I've got a storyboard on which I have a few views. Within one of these views I want an image to occupy the entire background, apparently to do this I need some code as ios won't by default load the iphone 5 larger image.

That's fine, I've found the code below...

```
    UIImage* redBG;
    CGFloat screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;

    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.f && screenHeight == 568.0f) {
        redBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-map-back-568h.png"];
    } else {
        redBG = [UIImage imageNamed:@"no-map-back.png"];
    }
```

My question is how, in code, do I reference either a new image that I drag myself onto the view in the storyboard, or failing that, just add the redBG image to the view directly through code?

When I add the image myself I can't see an ID for it anywhere in the storyboard so don't know what to use as a reference. If I add a line like:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImage *backImage;
```

I can't seem to 'connect' that to the image I've dragged onto the storyboard.

I've tried ctrl+click+drag but it isn't creating a connection. This appears to have changed since I last worked on an iPhone app back in the 70s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image that you added isn't an `UIImage`. It is a `UIImageView`.

Change your property to a `UIImageView` and it will work.

`UIImage` has no method of displaying itself directly.

Comment: THat's it thanks! Now of course I'm being told that the interface type cannot be statically allocated. But I'll beat this yet!